# Can't add more than one row to DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset

Here's the code:

```
DataSet1.CashRow CashRow = MainDataSet.Cash.NewCashRow();
CashRow.SetIdNull();
CashRow.Date = CashItem.Date;
CashRow.Description = CashItem.Description;
CashRow.Amount = CashItem.Amount;
MainDataSet.Cash.Rows.Add(CashRow);
```

It works just fine for the first time. However, if put in a cycle and simply doubled, no more rows are added. I have to close application and start it again.

Update: I have a DataGridView which is connected to the DataSet. Could this cause any problems? This issue is really weird, been trying to fix this for a week now. Maybe there are another ways to add rows?

Update 2: found the cause: "System.Data.ConstraintException: Column 'Id' is constrained to be unique.  Value '' is already present.".

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Jon, do you want to see shortened function which is this code from?

Comment: I think we just need more info. What 'no more rows are added' mean exactly? Errors, exceptions? What does the grid show?

Comment: No, just nothing happens. Neither the DataGridView, the DataSet or the Database change. DataSet.HasChanges() returns false on the second time.

Comment: I've spotted some strange behavior. On the first time HasChanges() and HasErrors() return a boolean value, but after trying to add another row, neither of these functions return anything. I think there is some problem in the DataSet.

Comment: Those functions can't return 'nothing'. Check again. Any empty `catch {}` blocks?

Comment: Thank you very much, Henk Holterman. Took me some time to find it.

Comment: @Technical: When I ask for a short but complete program, that's exactly what I mean: something we can copy, compile, run and see the problem. It doesn't need to be your real program - indeed, it shouldn't be - the point is for it to demonstrate *only* what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
DataSet1.CashRow CashRow = MainDataSet.Cash.NewCashRow();
CashRow.Date = CashItem.Date;
CashRow.Description = CashItem.Description;
CashRow.Amount = CashItem.Amount;

MainDataSet.Cash.AddCashRow(CashRow);

CashTableAdapter.Update(MainDataSet);
```

And if it still update only one row put this block as function, like this:

```
private void CreateCashRow (DateTime date, string description, int amount)
{
   DataSet1.CashRow CashRow = MainDataSet.Cash.NewCashRow();
   CashRow.Date = date;
   CashRow.Description = description;
   CashRow.Amount = amount;

   MainDataSet.Cash.AddCashRow(CashRow);

   CashTableAdapter.Update(MainDataSet);
}
```

And call the function as many time you need.

You must make sure you have PrimaryKey on the table

- I also suggest to you not to use so similar names for vars and types like you did with the CashRow.

Comment: Nope, sorry, neither worked. Even tried to update every table after adding a row.

Comment: the id column is an identity column (auto increment)?

Comment: and make sure the you have PrimaryKey

Comment: Turns out your idea about problem with primary key was right. I have "Id" column which is int primary key and auto increment. What values should I use to let the database assign a new ID itself?

Comment: you must have a primary key in your table when using dataset. and you can update the id by your self but it is preferred to let the SQL do this for you by changing the identity option to yes. then it will be auto increment. and you can set there the steps. default is start at 1 and step of 1.

Comment: You should wrap your tableadapters with a using statement. http://forums.asp.net/t/1396635.aspx?Dispose+tableadadapters+